# How to extract "editors will be allowed to add people and change the permissions" is checked?

Tags: google-drive-api

I will question the first time. I do not speak only a little English, but thank you I am.
We are using the "Google Apps for business".

Among the items that are shared with others set,
I wonder if it would be there a way to extract those "Editors will be allowed to add people and change the permissions" is checked.

Because it is a rule that you uncheck the above,
We would like to monitor the setting status.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `boolean` field in the `Files` resource which is named `writersCanShare`.

This field is exactly what you want.

Refer to https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files for more information about the Drive API